# Naming a .csv with text that can be updated each year

Tags: r, csv, naming

I'm looking for a way to automate the update of files names. The code will be used annually to download several .csv files. I would like to be able to change the `2020_2021` portion of the name to whatever assessment (i.e. `2021_2022, 2022_2023`etc.) year it is at the beginning of the script so the file names don't have to be updated manually.

```
write.csv(SJRML_00010,
          file = "SJRML__00010_2020_2021.csv")
write.csv(SJRML_00095,
          file = "SJRML_00095_2020_2021.csv")
write.csv(SJRML_00480,
          file = "SJRML_00480_2020_2021.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
lastyear <- 2020
prevassessment <- sprintf("%i_%i", lastyear, lastyear+1)
nextassessment <- sprintf("%i_%i", lastyear+1, lastyear+2)
prevassessment
# [1] "2020_2021"
filenames <- c("SJRML__00010_2020_2021.csv", "SJRML_00095_2020_2021.csv")
gsub(prevassessment, nextassessment, filenames, fixed = TRUE)
# [1] "SJRML__00010_2021_2022.csv" "SJRML_00095_2021_2022.csv"
```

You can do the `gsub` on a vector of filenames or one at a time, however you are implementing your processing.

Comment: Is there a way to do this within the written files names? For example: ```AssessmentYear -> 2020_2021``` and then each files name contains some form of `AssessmentYear`,    
`filenames <- c("SJRML__00010_*AssessmentYear*.csv"`      
so that it is a simple line at the start of the script?

Comment: Are you using `list.files(..)` to get the existing file names? Your question is not really clear as I don't know what else you are doing.

Comment: Sorry, I'm brand new to R so learning how best to search for and ask questions. I'm pulling multiple data files from a database and then saving them as .csv. The files are named by location, data, type and year. This action will be conducted annually, so I wanted to be able to update the names of all the files to reflect the year.

Comment: If you are pulling data from a database and then saving as CSVs, what does it matter what the previous files are named? Aren't the names generated based on current data?

Comment: They are but the data will be compared across all assessment years, so it would be beneficial to have the years included in the naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

To create a .csv with name that can be updated
`Year <- "_2020"` 
then
`write.csv(file_name, paste0("file_name", Year,".csv"))`
This returns `file_name_2020.csv`